# Segfault while using wcslen in C

Tags: c, string, printf, widechar

In C, I get a segfault while doing

```
const wchar_t *id = L"{{content}}\0";
wprintf(L"%s\n", wcslen(id));
```

I don't understand what's wrong here... Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Are you trying to print the length of the string, or the string?  Also, why are you using wchar_t in the first place?  It's almost always better to use UTF-8 in plain `char` (unless you're on Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dereference the pointer converted from size_t, and wprintf expects the pointer for the %s . Use %zu to display the length.

Comment: Oh I see... Thanks a lot!